# Which Schema types are considered by Google to show review snippets with star-rating votes?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

My webpage is devoted to generic places, where users vote for them, and I'm trying to make Google to show rich snippets with star-rating votes for such webpages.

I've been reading the [Schema.org documentation](https://schema.org/docs/full.html), and found two types which can help me:

- [`Place`](https://schema.org/Place)
- [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article)

However, I've been browsing the webpage of Google dealing with [review snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet), and they claim that publishers can "supply ratings for the following content" types:

> - Books
> - Local businesses
> - Movies
> - Music
> - Products
> - Recipes

Are such categories the only accepted ones to show review snippets?

I see some webpages using `Article` or just the [`hReview-aggregate` Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview-aggregate) without mentioning the type, to show review snippets.

Which would be the best solution? `Place`? `Article`? Just Microformat?

Comment: You found a page which gets the star rating in Google Search for an `Article`? Can you provide a link? And same question for `hReview-aggregate`: do you have a link for a page that gets a star rating by only using this Microformat?

Answer (score 0):

Schema.org is quite flexible to mix elements as you wish, but so far Google will handle only some specific cases, the ones listed in their [reference page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet)